# parse json data returned by youtube

Tags: javascript, json

I am new bee trying some javascript to read the   json data below , I want to parse json data returned by youtube  api.

Url for json data  https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk?v=2&alt=json

the data returned by this url

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","entry":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$media":"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","xmlns$yt":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007","gd$etag":"W/\"CkIDSH47eCp7I2A9Wh5VFks.\"","id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:SPtEUAFm6Yk"},"published":{"$t":"2010-02-13T17:09:09.000Z"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-12-10T07:29:39.000Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"},{"scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat","term":"Travel","label":"Travel & Events"}],"title":{"$t":"Atlanta Winter"},"content":{"type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","src":"https://www.youtube.com/v/SPtEUAFm6Yk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPtEUAFm6Yk&feature=youtube_gdata"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk/related?v=2"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile","type":"text/html","href":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=SPtEUAFm6Yk"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UGJ8B_nJw0dEyWyLZi5m4Q?v=2"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk?v=2"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Jason Gifford"},"uri":{"$t":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/jgiff76"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"UGJ8B_nJw0dEyWyLZi5m4Q"}}],"yt$accessControl":[{"action":"comment","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"commentVote","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"videoRespond","permission":"moderated"},{"action":"rate","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"embed","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"list","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"autoPlay","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"syndicate","permission":"allowed"}],"gd$comments":{"gd$feedLink":{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk/comments?v=2","countHint":0}},"media$group":{"media$category":[{"$t":"Travel","label":"Travel & Events","scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"}],"media$content":[{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/v/SPtEUAFm6Yk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","medium":"video","isDefault":"true","expression":"full","duration":224,"yt$format":5},{"url":"rtsp://r3---sn-p5qlsu7z.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmJ6WYBUET7SBMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","type":"video/3gpp","medium":"video","expression":"full","duration":224,"yt$format":1},{"url":"rtsp://r3---sn-p5qlsu7z.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmJ6WYBUET7SBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","type":"video/3gpp","medium":"video","expression":"full","duration":224,"yt$format":6}],"media$credit":[{"$t":"jgiff76","role":"uploader","scheme":"urn:youtube","yt$display":"Jason Gifford"}],"media$description":{"$t":"A rare snow that sticks in the south.  Reminds me of being a kid.  Feels more like Michigan than Georgia.","type":"plain"},"media$keywords":{},"media$license":{"$t":"youtube","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.youtube.com/t/terms"},"media$player":{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPtEUAFm6Yk&feature=youtube_gdata_player"},"media$restriction":[{"$t":"DE","type":"country","relationship":"deny"}],"media$thumbnail":[{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/default.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:52","yt$name":"default"},{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/mqdefault.jpg","height":180,"width":320,"yt$name":"mqdefault"},{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/hqdefault.jpg","height":360,"width":480,"yt$name":"hqdefault"},{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/1.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:00:56","yt$name":"start"},{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/2.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:52","yt$name":"middle"},{"url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SPtEUAFm6Yk/3.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:02:48","yt$name":"end"}],"media$title":{"$t":"Atlanta Winter","type":"plain"},"yt$aspectRatio":{"$t":"widescreen"},"yt$duration":{"seconds":"224"},"yt$uploaded":{"$t":"2010-02-13T17:09:09.000Z"},"yt$uploaderId":{"$t":"UCUGJ8B_nJw0dEyWyLZi5m4Q"},"yt$videoid":{"$t":"SPtEUAFm6Yk"}},"gd$rating":{"average":5.0,"max":5,"min":1,"numRaters":1,"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"},"yt$statistics":{"favoriteCount":"0","viewCount":"356"},"yt$rating":{"numDislikes":"0","numLikes":"1"}}}
```

my code to parse  this

```
alert($.getJSON(mydata));
  alert($.getJSON(mydata).version);
```

I get undefined for any property I  retrieve from the  $.getJson(mydata).

jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/fachhoch/gE96Q/1/

Please help how to parse the above object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1348195

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON(mydata).version` is not correct and that's why you're getting an undefined.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk?v=2&alt=json", function( data ) {
     console.log(data.version);
});
```

`console.log` shows up in your browsers console window.

Comment: I wan to render the  json data in my underscore template, so I want to call the url get the json object pass it to the view and call properties using dot notation , please advice how to ?,the one you gave works but I cannot go with that unless I retrieve all the properties   and set it to some other object   in the callback function  for $.getJSON('...url', function(){}).

Comment: I tried this
<code>
 var  myObject;
    $.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SPtEUAFm6Yk?v=2&alt=json", function( data ) {
        myObject=data;
        // here it prints fine.
  console.log(myObject.entry.content.src);
    });
   // this says undefined
   console.log(myObject);
 </code>
 
 pleae advie how to capture the result inot an object and use it later to retriee properties

Comment: the callbacks are async. $.getJSON executes then immediately goes to console.log(myObject). Later when $.getJSON returns with the youtube data it then calls the callback function. By that time the console.log(myObject) already ran. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gE96Q/4/

Comment: I am   building app with backbone js, my thought is call the json data set it to my model and  use it   in the view , if the getjson  is async then obviously my model will contain null and my template will  render it as null, please advice what  developers   do to overcome this aync behaviour I am new bee to javascript

Comment: Suggestion, don't use backbone until you get a good grasp of javascript and aync callbacks. Consider reading this book, [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596517742/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0596517742&linkCode=as2&tag=jparm-20). It's the best place to start learning JS.